# Condition on a & b so that the two tangents drawn to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ from a point are normals to the parabola $x^2=4by$

Tags: conic-sections

> Find the condition on a & b so that the two tangents drawn to the
>   parabola $y^2=4ax$ from a point are normals to the parabola $x^2=4by$

I tried finding the joint equation of tangents to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ like $SS_1=T^2$.Then I tried to apply the condition of normality to the joint pair of straight lines.But its becoming too huge.Please let me know if you can think of a shorter and more elegant method to prove $a^2>8b^2$.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a ton @labbhattacharjee...check this one too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459857/condition-on-x-coordinate-of-a-point-such-that-three-distinct-normals-can-be-dra

Comment: See https://www.google.im/advanced_search  for exact search